# Why does the class variable change?

Tags: python

So I was programming something in python that had to do with assigning a class variable to an instance variable, and then changing the instance variable inside the **init** method. I simplified the code a bit, when I run it the class variable gets changed as well:

```
class Map():
    map = [1,2,3]

    def __init__(self): 
        self.map = Map.map
        for i in range(len(self.map)):
            self.map[i] = self.map[i] * 2

        print("self.map =", self.map)
        print("Map.map =", Map.map)

new_map = Map()
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
self.map = [1, 4, 9]
Map.map = [1, 4, 9]
```

Basically I was wondering why Map.map gets changed even though I only changed self.map?

Comment: I thought you made it pretty clear that `self.map = Map.map`.

Comment: But if I make Map.map a integer, delete the for loop, and then change self.map, Map.map does not change; I guess that was my question

Comment: @user2776708 Because then you wouldn’t be changing `self.Map`’s *content*, you would be *reassigning* it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
    self.map = Map.map[:]
```

The reason is that when you do `self.map = Map.map`, `self.map` is pointing to the same object as `Map.map`. So when you mutate `self.map` you are also mutating `Map.map` because it's the same object. It's the same phenomenon as here:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> a
[4, 2, 3]
>>> b is a
True
```

What you instead want to do is **copy** the object. You can copy lists by doing `list(a)` or `a[:]`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[4, 2, 3]
>>> b is a
False
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, **assignment is not copying!** It just gives you another name to access the same object.

If the object is immutable, such as a number or string, you won't notice the difference. But when you do an assignment to a mutable object such as a list, any changes made to that object get reflected in all the other assigned names, since they're still the same object.

To make a copy of a list you can use slice notation (the slice does a copy) or you can use [the `copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

`self.map` and `Map.map` are both pointing to the same list. In Python parlance, `self.map` and `Map.map` are both names for the same list.

Check to see if `id(self.map) == id(Map.map)`, and you'll find that to be `True`.

To get the behavior you want, [assign a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/700228) of Map.map to self.map.

Use either [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

```
self.map = list(Map.map)
```

or the slice syntax

```
self.map = Map.map[:]
```

The [builtin copy module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) can be used for this as well, especially if you have nested lists.

Answer (score -1):

As others have noted, it's because you are using a mutable class variable.

As you are using the same list for all instances, having a class variable is pointless.

```
class Map():
    map = [1,2,3]
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = Map.map[:]
```

Is completely functionally equivalent with:

```
class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = [1,2,3]
```

Which is much easier to understand.

In general, mutable class variables is a bad idea, except for some very specific circumstances.

Comment: No. This is unrelated to mutability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No it's not. If he had done exactly the same thing with a string it would have worked.

Comment: It wouldn’t have worked – strings don’t support item assignment so you don’t even run into this situation.